ILU Construction Question
The algorithm in Yousef Saad's book Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems gives the ILU(0) algorithm as follows: 
where $NZ(A) = \{(i, j): a_{ij} \neq 0\}$. My question is, how are the matrices $L$ and $U$ constructed based on the algorithm? We know that both $L$ and $U$ have the same sparsity pattern as $A$, but just do not see it from the algorithm here.

The algorithm as you've quoted doesn't refer to any matrices named $L$ and $U$.
